# how to pass some key-value pairs to redis zadd?

Tags: redis, lua

I'm trying to add multiple key-value pairs to sorted set,like this:

```lua
   local status_and_score = redis.call('zrevrange', 'time_1', 0, 100, 'WITHSCORES')

   -- redis.call('zadd', 'time_2', status_table)
```

how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zadd key score member [[score member] [score member] …]  1
```

```
local status_table = {100, "value1", 200, "value2"}
redis.call("ZADD", "time_1", unpack(status_table))
```

Comment: local status_table = {100, "value1", 200, "value2"}

Comment: redis.call("ZADD", "time_1", unpack(status_table))

Comment: Use the editors function to mark code properly. This makes your post more readable. Use the edit function instead of adding comments ;)